# C++ - Freeing memory allocated in main but pointed to in a seperate class

Tags: c++, memory-management

I was wondering, if I create an object in main using the new keyword, then set that object (pointer) to be pointed to by a member of another class, setting the original pointer to null, where would I delete the allocated memory? I could do it in the second class's destructor but what if that object wasn't dynamically allocated?

Some code as an example:

```
World world;
Player* newPlayer = new Player("Ted");
world.setPlayer(newPlayer);
newPlayer = 0;
```

So now the 'player' member variable in World is pointing to the memory allocated by newPlayer and newPlayer is pointing to null. How should I deallocate this memory when I'm done with the World object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call delete when you are finished. To avoid the need for this though look into making use of shared pointers as they will relieve you of the need to do this.

Edit: To answer your comment, where you call `delete` depends on your application but ensure that you

1. Dont `delete` it before you have allocated it.
2. Dont `delete` it until you are sure nothing else needs to access it.

A possible place would be in the destructor of your World object, but it is impossible to say without knowing details of the rest of your application. This is why `boost::shared_ptr` is preferable.

Comment: Where should I call delete? Surely if I called it straight afterwards it would delete the memory that's now pointed to by the player member of World and I'd end up with a dangling pointer? I know I should use smart/shared pointers but at the moment I'm trying to learn all the ins and outs of memory management in C++ ... the hard way =P Thanks for the advice though

Comment: Alternatively create the objects on the stack and copy the data rather than use pointers if the objects are small enough then C++ scope rules will destroy them

Comment: Downvote? I will happily acknowledge that this is not the best answer here (despite being accepted) but have I actually stated anything that is explicitly wrong? If so I would like to know - I am only an intermediate level coder and would like to know if there are problems in my knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

This kind of complexity is why you should try to avoid raw pointers in C++.  [Smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) exist to solve this kind of problem, and save you the headache of manually tracking who has ownership of an object and when to delete it.

For example:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Player> sp_Player;

struct World {
    sp_Player player;
    World(sp_Player p) : player(p) {}
};


sp_Player newPlayer = new Player("Ted");

World world;
world.setPlayer(newPlayer);

// Object is now automatically deleted at the correct time!
```

Comment: Without knowing the exact semantics of his objects, it's difficult to say, but the names suggest a game, with player a player in the game.  In that case, the usual smart pointers are probably a bad choice; the lifetime of a player is logically determined by the game, and not by whether some bit of code happens to hold a pointer to it or not.  In which case, using `boost::shared_ptr` is a serious design error, which will cause no end of problems down the road.

Comment: @JamesKanze: If the object was created by `World`, then I'd agree, as it would be reasonably easy to follow the rule of three.  But if object construction occurs externally to the `World` class (as the OP is implying), then what's the alternative?  A complex system of destructors/copy constructors that tracks whether the object was dynamically allocated, and conditionally calls `delete`?

Comment: I like the idea of using a factory function in `World` to create the objects, since this allows defining their relationship with world at the moment of creation.  But I don't buy the issue of possible allocation on the stack: judging from the names in the example, `Player` is designed to be dynamically allocated, and so shouldn't be allocated on the stack.  (If this is really a worry, the solution would be to declare the destructor private, and provide a "killer" member function which does the delete.)

Answer (score 4):

As noted in other answers it is easier to use smart pointers however in this case you can put the delete elsewhere.

If all players are passed to a `World` then `World` can deal with the memory - every time a `World` is destructed or when a different player is set the the `Player` that `World` holds has to be deleted. Also no Player should be destroyed anywhere else or otherwise it could be destroyed twice. However in this case I would make all Players be constructed by a method in `World` to keep it clear who owns the memory management and keep the same class creating and destroying the Player objects

Some very incomplete code is (note how the smart pointer code is much less and I think covers all cases - this does not)

```
class World
{
   Player *p;
 ...
}

World() : p(nullptr) {
  ...
}

~World() {
    delete p;
}

void World setPlayer( Palyer *aP ) {
    if ( p != aP) {
         delete p;
    }
    p = aP;
    ....
}

Player* World::createPlayer(std::string const& name){ 
  return new Player(name); 
}
```

Note `= Player(name)` creates a Playeobject on the stack and that is not managed in your code by new and delete - and might be the best solution here.

Also need to deal with operator= and the copy constructor (for the latter best to stop it ever being called or it will need to duplicate the Player object so deleting the Original World and the copy will not both attempt to delete the same Player)

Comment: So something like
    " void World::createPlayer(char* name){ player = Player(name); } " ?

Comment: +1 for suggesting a factory function in `World`.  That's a very good idea for making it clear who's running the show.

Answer (score 1):

There is no absolute answer.  The question is: why are you allocating
the object dynamically to begin with?  Once you've answered this, it's
usually obvious where it should be deleted.

From the names of your objects, for example, I'd guess that `world` owns
everything; that it decides the lifetime of players, etc.  In which
case, it should be responsible for the `delete`.  As for the possibiltiy
of allocating a `Person` on the stack: don't do that.  Given that
`Person` probably has a definitely lifetime which *doesn't* correspond
to a block in a function (otherwise, why allocate it dynamically to
begin with), it doesn't make sense to declare local variables of that
type.

Comment: I think this is the best summary. Oli's and my answer give particular solutions but you need to decide the best depending on your design.

Comment: I wasn't actually going to dynamically allocate the player in code, I just wanted to know what would happen if I did =)

Answer (score -1):

new should always followed by delete. If you set the pointer to point to some other object without freeing up the memory it will result in [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)

Comment: Yes but not necessarily in the same block